# How to overwrite existing zip file instead of updating it in Info-Zip?

Tags: command-line, zip

To obtain a fresh zip file just like as tar does, do I have to perform `rm foo.zip` before executing `zip`?

```
$ mkdir foo; touch foo/bar
$ zip -r foo.zip foo
  adding: foo/ (stored 0%)
  adding: foo/bar (stored 0%)
$ rm foo/bar; touch foo/baz
$ zip -r foo.zip foo
  adding: foo/ (stored 0%)
  adding: foo/baz (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l foo.zip
Archive:  foo.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2011-10-27 07:49   foo/
        0  2011-10-27 07:49   foo/bar
        0  2011-10-27 07:49   foo/baz
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the -FS option to "file sync"

```
zip -FSr foo.zip foo
```

This will add any new files in the folder to the zip, and delete any files from the zip that aren't in the folder.

Comment: Which version of zip has this option?  My zip command does not recognise "-S"

Comment: The switch is `-FS` not `-F` and `-S` together.  This has been there since zip 3.0 at least.  Check `man zip`.

Comment: How is "new file" defined? Its filesize changes, date modified, both? Just curious

Comment: This just work for `Zip 3.0` and don't work for `Zip 2.32` (didn't remove old files in zip pack)

Comment: You mean `-FS -r`, right?

Comment: Can this answer be updated to explain `-r`?

Answer (score 17):

An alternative to using the `-FS` option (or deleting the old ZIP file first), is to *overwrite* the existing ZIP file by having `zip` output to stdout and redirect it to the designated file:

```
zip -r - foo >foo.zip
```

If `foo.zip` exists, it will be overwritten by shell redirection, meaning you'll get a fresh new ZIP file 100% of the time, every time.

| Option | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `-r` | Recursively add directory and its contents |
| `-` | Output ZIP contents to stdout |
| `foo` | The directory to be zipped |
| `>foo.zip` | Redirect stdout to file `foo.zip` |

Comment: You mean output to stdout

Comment: It may be slower than the -FS option because it will compress again files that have not changed since the time the archive was updated.