# How to get zip to update file in an archive even if the file on the filesystem is older

Tags: linux, zip

If I have the following zip:

```
my.zip
|- folder
|  `- to-update.txt
`- some-other-file.txt
```

and a folder structure:

```
working-directory
`- folder
   `- to-update.txt
```

I wish to copy the file `to-update.txt` from my working directory into the zip. To do that I would use:

```sh
# Currently in working-directory
zip -ru /path/to/my.zip .
```

However, if `my.zip`'s copy of `to-update.txt` is newer, this will not work and zip outputs (with `-v`):

> zip diagnostic: `folder/` up to date
> zip diagnostic: `folder/to-update.txt` up to date

How can I get it to overwrite any files (and still add new ones) from my filesystem/working directory even if they have an older timestamp?

Unlike the [file-sync option](https://superuser.com/questions/350991/how-to-overwrite-existing-zip-file-instead-of-updating-it-in-info-zip), I do not want to remove missing files, so `some-other-file.txt` should remain untouched.

Comment: Doesn't simply `zip my.zip Folder/to-update.txt` do what you want? In my test it does.

Comment: I want to sync the whole folder. There may be multiple files in `folder` or even in `working-directory`.

Comment: Then recursivlty, like `zip -r my.zip folder/`

Comment: Yep, seems to work, thank you. Please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Added as an answer

Comment: Note that the operation you are asking for is "replace" not "update", and that's why the update flag was counterproductive.

Comment: @BenVoigt but his issue was that there is no outright "replace" flag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply re-adding the files to the archive should accomplish this:

```sh
zip -r my.zip .
```

`-u` does the same but only if the files are newer.

Answer (score 1):

My (hacky) solution is to change/update the timestamps of the files. As it was in a Docker container, we can live with it.

With touch, built from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090731/recursively-touch-files-with-file) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13525005):

```sh
find working-directory -mindepth 1 -exec touch -m {} +
```

- `-mindepth` ignores the working directory: `.`
- `-m` only changes the modified timestamp and leaves the access timestamp
- `+` instead of `\;` is the difference between `touch -m x y z` and `touch x && touch y && touch z`

As I was in Docker though, I did not have write access to the files and had to copy them before zipping them:

```sh
cp -r working-directory /tmp/working-directory/
(cd /tmp/working-directory && zip -ru /path/to/my.zip .)
rm -rf /tmp/working-directory
```

Not the nicest solution, but it'll do. If anyone has any one-liners with `zip` (installing `unzip`, for instance, is not desired), please feel free to post them.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to delete the file before adding it again:

```
zip -rd /path/to/my.zip to-update.txt
zip -ru /path/to/my.zip to-update.txt
```

(As I'm not using `zip`, the commands above were written theoretically.)

Comment: `-d` doesn't delete with `-r`. `-d` on its own requires a list of files, so this doesn't work as given for the specified use case, where the files to update/delete are defined by the directory structure.